# How can I obtain a value from a stored procedure (SELECT COUNT) in c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, count, nullreferenceexception

I'm using a stored procedure to count and validate if a username already exists in the database, but the problem isn't there, my problem is when I try to obtain the value of the SELECTION in C# in some blogs I found this code:

```
// Create ConnectionString
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectPractice"].ConnectionString;

// Check if the username is not in the DataBase
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmo = new SqlCommand("spBuscaUsuarioMail", con);
cmo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", 1);

SqlParameter NroUserName = new SqlParameter("@Num_de_Usuarios", 0);
NroUserName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmo.Parameters.Add(NroUserName);

con.Open();

int contarUsername = Int32.Parse(cmo.Parameters["@Num_de_Usuarios"].Value.ToString());
```

This seems to be great! And it looks like function very well but then in the last part `int contarUsername = Int32.Parse...` C# gives me an exception that is the next:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.
>   Object reference not set o an instance of an object.

Then, in troubleshooting tips I read:

- Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method.
- Use the "new keyword to create an object instance.
- Get general help for this exception.

I tried a lot of things, but now I feel really tired and I can't think in a new solution.

This is the stored procedure I'm using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBuscaUsuarioMail
   @Username CHAR (25),
   @Num_de_Usuarios INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @Num_de_Usuarios = COUNT (UserName)
    FROM dbo.Usuarios
    WHERE UserName = @Username
END

EXEC spBuscaUsuarioMail '1', @Num_de_Usuarios OUTPUT
SELECT @Num_de_Usuarios
```

Comment: Can you explain the stray asterisks lying around your code?

Comment: Very confused question. Without seeing the code of the stored procedure it is difficult to answer

Comment: If you can add the script for the stored proc that will help people see your problem

Comment: Thanks! I put the sp in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your parameters....

In the stored procedure, you have

```
@Username CHAR (25),
@Num_de_Usuarios INT OUTPUT
```

yet in your C# code, you set up both of them as `int`, it seems:

```
cmo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", 1);

SqlParameter NroUserName = new SqlParameter("@Num_de_Usuarios", 0);
NroUserName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmo.Parameters.Add(NroUserName);
```

I think you need to set up the `@Username` parameter as a string - and give it some meaningful value!

```
cmo.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.Char, 25).Value = "Steve";  // or whatever
```

And of course, as @Steve already mentioned: you need to actually **execute** your stored procedure before you can read out the `OUTPUT` parameter!

Comment: Really thanks! I can see the problems, I'm still a beginner, your answer help me a lot.

Comment: I have another question... I think I can't have and AddWithValue with 3 arguments... I'm not sure, but I c# I have another error saying that

Comment: @user3850665: sorry - yes - it should have been `cmo.Parameters.Add(...)` - fixed my post.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it... tomorrow I'll post the solution for other people who wants the same.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't execute the command it is really difficult to get the value of an output parameter

```
 cmo.Parameters.Add(NroUserName);
 con.Open();
 cmo.ExecuteNonQuery();
 int contarUsername = Convert.ToInt32(cmo.Parameters["@Num_de_Usuarios"].Value);
```

Also the last two lines of the Stored procedure, if they are really in the sp code are meaningless, you don't need them and you get a recursive call on the same stored procedure until somethink breaks . You should remove them

```
-- remove these two lines
EXEC spBuscaUsuarioMail '1', @Num_de_Usuarios OUTPUT
SELECT @Num_de_Usuarios
```

Also look at the answer from @marc_s, he points to another problem in your code.

Comment: When I used cmo.ExecuteNonQuery C# gives me this exception: SqlException was unhandled by user code. Mazimun stored procedure, function, trigger or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: Do you have that two last lines in the stored procedure? They are useless and create a recursive loop that calls again and again the stored procedure

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't Vote Up because I'm new in this blog, but really thanks, I could see my error and I don't have exceptions anymore, I still cannot make it work, but now I'm in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. It works!

```
            string connectionString = connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectPractice"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            SqlCommand cmo = new SqlCommand("spBuscaUsuario", con);
            cmo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmo.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.Char, 25).Value = txtUsername.Text;
            SqlParameter NroUserName = new SqlParameter("@Num_de_Usuarios", 0);
            NroUserName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmo.Parameters.Add(NroUserName);
            con.Open();
            cmo.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int contarUsername = Int32.Parse(cmo.Parameters["@Num_de_Usuarios"].Value.ToString());
```

And this is the Stored Procedure...

CREATE PROCEDURE spBuscaUsuario

@Username CHAR (25),
@Num_de_Usuarios INT OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT @Num_de_Usuarios = COUNT (UserName)
FROM dbo.Usuarios
WHERE UserName = @Username
```

END

I expect this code be useful for someone else.

Comment: Thank you to Marc_s and Steve, You helped me a lot